# How can a reduce the read speed of a Liteon DVD drive under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, htpc, optical-drive

How can I reduce the read speed of a Liteon DVD drive under Windows 7? The aim is to reduce the level of noise generated by an wasteful high-speed as it's used in an HTPC environment.

Comment: Toshiba CD/DVD Drive Acoustic Silencer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many utilities out there to do this.  The trick is finding one that works with your drive. :)

[Here's a list of such utilities](http://forum.rpc1.org/viewtopic.php?t=26740).

I've personally had success with the second one on the list ([CD Bremse](http://www.cd-bremse.de/cdbremse.htm), aka "CD Brake" in English).

Comment: It seems to forget the settings after a reboot...?